# how to push data to existing sapui5 model

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I have a Json Model in sapui5 as - //console.log(dModel);

[image]

My new data response is as follows - //console.log(response);

[image]

Now I want to push new data(only the data part) to the existing model, inside /modelData/data.

code I am trying -

```
sap.ui.getCore().getModel().getProperty("/modelData/data").push(response.data);
```

This code is pushing the data but as -

[image]

After 19(old values) it is pushing all the objects inside 20th as 0, 1, 2... The Ideal way should be after 19 I should get 20, 21, 22 and so on.

What changes I need to make to get this, Thank you ... please suggest.

Comment: What is not happening ?

Comment: see the last image all the values are pushed inside 20th

Comment: I am unable to access images.. Do you find any error in console ? Could you see updated data after `.push` ?

Comment: last image is after updating only, Please check the image if possible...:)

Comment: _"last image is after updating only"_ ? Did not get you!

Comment: The code is working,there is no error. But all the objects from the response.data are getting pushed inside one object(new one at last) of the existing model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109803/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-namita-kalita).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){

       sap.ui.getCore().getModel().getProperty("/modelData/data").push(response.data[i]) 

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to add new items to your model, you should use it like this:

```
var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
var aData  = oModel.getProperty("/modelData/data");
aData.push.apply(aData, response.data);
oModel.setProperty("/modelData/data", aData);
```

The difference is you first retrieve the array with data, add to the array, and then set the property with the updated array

Edit: Ok, makes sense now: you are adding an array to an array. And using 'push' just adds a new entry with whatever object you are adding. So you are adding a single entry (which happens to be an array)
See updated answer

Comment: Hi Qualiture, your code also giving me the same model as my last image, where as I want data to pushed as 19,20,21 so on

Comment: Then the received response in response.data is not a proper array; check the returned value for response.data. I do this kind of 'adding to a model array' all the time without any issues ;-)